# PDO SQLITE Escape single quote backslash

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Using PDO to CRUD with SQLITE3.  When I insert a string 'didn't', the string goes into the table as 'didn\'t'.

So, later when I read the string back out, to ouput to HTML, I get didn\'t in my web page.

So, if PDO is escaping the single quote on the INSERT with the backslash, how do I strip out the escaping backslashes for presentation?

Does that make sense?

EDIT - Including code.  $eventBody is the string in question.

```
try {
               $db = new PDO('sqlite:../posts.sqlite');
                $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
                }
            catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                    die;
                }
                    //using the sqlite functions to do date/time stuff
        $query = 'INSERT INTO posts (eDay, eMonth, eYear, eTitle, eBody,author, eURL, eTime)
                  VALUES( strftime(\'%d\',\'now\') , strftime(\'%m\',\'now\') , strftime(\'%Y\',\'now\') ,"'. $eventTitle .'","'.$eventBody.'","' . $eventAuthor. '","' . $eventURL . '",time(\'now\',\'localtime\'));' ;

                try
                {
                $result=$db->query($query);
                if(!($result))
                {
                    echo "INSERT FAILED.<br>";
                    echo "QUERY STRING: ".$query ." <br>";
                    die;

                }
                    echo "Successfully Added Record";
                    $eventTitle = '';
                    $eventBody='';
                    $eventURL='';
                    $eventAuthor='';
            //      urlRedirect("Referback.php");
                }
                catch (PDOException $ex)
                {
                    echo $ex->getMessage();
                    die;
                }
                catch (Exception $exc)
                {
                    echo $exc->getMessage();
                    die;
                }
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide us the code of the insertion?

Comment: Okay, the way you build your query cannot work because you're mixing PHP and SQL together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO works the way it should, you should check how you do your insert (build the queries) and the data source (meaning what's coming from `$_POST`/`$_GET`).

And specially the [magic quotes gpc](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc). If you don't know what it is, check it out. It's a very recurrent problem. Before you start using `stripslashes`/`addslashes` and such.

You should also use the [prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), it's not only nicer, but a lot less work and safer.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO posts '.
    '(eDay, eMonth, eYear, eTitle, eBody, author, eURL, eTime) '.
    'VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);');
$result = $stmt->execute(array(
    date('d'),
    date('m'),
    date('Y'),
    $eventTitle,
    $eventBody,
    $eventAuthor,
    $eventURL,
    time('now', 'localtime')
));
```

You could also print the data you give to ̀ execute` to make sure, it is what you want.

Comment: Thank you greut.  I've seen posts about prepared statements and I guess I've been trying to avoid a rewrite.  I use Store Procedures in MS SQL frequently (for work) and this approach is somewhat similar.  I'll give it a shot.  Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Gruet, your code worked great out of the box. But, the string still gets stored in the table as didn\'t.

Comment: check the `magic_quote_gpc` and var_dump the array you give to `execute` to be sure everything is okay there.

Comment: Ok, I added the function in Example #2 on this site and it's all good.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php